# Is there a way to define a common "local proxy repo"?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I dislike having the same git repo multiple times on my system in different places, as I find that disorganized and messy, not to mention the wasted duplicated storage space and network bandwidth for fetching etc. But especially with multiple projects including the same dependencies as submodules this often happens for me.

What I would really like to have is like a git configuration "whenever you want to clone `<upstream-url>`, create a sort-of proxy repo instead that has its own checkout and current branch/commit info, but all commands accessing the actual repo content (like fetch or commit) are done on (resp. proxied to) a common local repo at `<local-path>`".

Note that I want this to be a global git config thing, this should not require any change to the submodule configuration of each project.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: What you describe is similar to worktrees, but I think that's not what you actually want.

Comment: I think you can do this with [URL rewriting using `insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf). Clone the repository once, configure URL rewriting as `git config --global url.file:///path/to/local/clone.insteadOf https://host/repo` and now every time Git gonna clone/pull/push a submodule from/to `https://host/repo` it will actually clone/pull/push it from/to the rewritten local `file:///` URL. See stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+insteadOf . Additional hooks can be used in the local clone to forward pushes back to the origin.

Comment: @phd hm I'd say this is a pretty imperfect approximation of what I want, as it still creates full clones of the common repo and requires a fairly complex setup... how would you make origin "pushable" with hooks, wouldn't that url rewriting make the actual origin inaccessible?

Comment: "*…this is a pretty imperfect approximation of what I want…*" I don't see any other way; the only alternative is the current duplication. "*…how would you make origin "pushable" with hooks…*" Create a `post-update` hook in the local "proxy" clone that pushes new commits back to the origin. All submodules point to the proxy clone, any push from them will be pushed to the proxy, and the hook will re-push them back to the origin in a true proxy model.

Comment: After a local experiment I elaborate the comments into [an asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77852335/7976758).

Comment: https://github.com/motemen/git-shared-submodule-update Found in https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=git+submodule+shared+clone#ip=1

Answer (score 1):

Elaborated from [my comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77851134/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-common-local-proxy-repo#comment137246947_77851134).

There is no simple way to do what you want with just one-line configuration. You can do this with [URL rewriting using `insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf). Clone the repository once, configure URL rewriting:

```
git config --global url.file:///path/to/local/clone.insteadOf https://host/repo
```

and now every time Git clones/pulls/pushes a submodule from/to `https://host/repo` it will actually clone/pull/push it from/to the rewritten local `file://` URL.

Please be warned that due to security issue [CVE-2022-39253](https://www.cve.org/CVERecord?id=CVE-2022-39253) `file://` transport in recent versions of Git is disabled for submodules. You can re-enable it temporary prepending `git -c protocol.file.allow=always` for every `git submodule` command, for example

```
git -c protocol.file.allow=always submodule update
```

Or you can allow it permanently:

```
git config --global protocol.file.allow always
```

Additionally you can add a [`post-receive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive) or a `post-update` hook to the "proxy" repository. Any push from local clones will be pushed to the "proxy" repository, and the hook will re-push them back to the origin in a true proxy model. Example of the `post-update` hook:

```bash
#! /bin/sh
# push all updated branches
exec git push origin "$@"
```

The inverse task — update all your local clones  when the "proxy" repository is updated — is harder to implement but still possible. Instead of `git fetch (or pull) origin` create a script that runs fetch/pull and then updates the clones. Unfortunately there is no way for the "proxy" repo to know how many time you've cloned it so the list of local clones should be updated manually, alas.

Comment: A clever idea, but this still does not prevent having multiple copies of the same repo, all potentially with their own branches and commits, so for me this doesn't really do enough of what I wanted to be worth the hassle.

Comment: @zse Submodules are checked out repositories. They have working trees checked out at different commits. So what you said (having one copy of all submodules) is absolutely impossible. IWBN if you think about it and explain better what you really want — considering everything already said about submodules. If you just feel uncomfortable having many different working trees of a shared submodule — nothing could help, there is no way around that. You can simplify things a bit by forcing all copies of the submodule to be on the same commit. Then you could replace the working trees with symlinks.

Comment: It seems impossible with current git, I agree. But it is not impossible in theory, so this just means git simply does not have the feature I want right now. Maybe in the future git will add more flexibility of seperating the repo content from a working tree checkout.

Comment: @zse What would be a solution for having multiple working trees checked out at different commits and not having multiple working trees at all? Seems contradictory to me.

Comment: I may be missing something, but I see no reason why a working tree would internally need a full copy of the repo's content. The commits, branches etc could all be shared, the only thing that needs to be unique to each working tree is the checkout plus some info where the checkout came from.

Comment: @zse That's probably possible to do with Git now by manually pointing gitlink (the file `.git` — the file, not directory — at the top of the checked out submodule tree) to the shared `.git` directory. `echo gitdir: /path/to/shared/repo/.git > .git` . See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout#_description

Comment: I believe that would share "too much". Each working tree should still remember where it is currently checked out.

Comment: @zse Ah, no, that currently impossible or rather hard in Git. Perhaps [`git clone --local`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt--l) or `--shared` but that's a wild guess from me.